# I need to make it so that if parent1 !== and parent 2 is !== then it returns true, atm if either of them is !== it returns true

Tags: javascript

I'm rly sorry if I didn't ask this question in the best way etc, but I am extremely new to coding, and if you need any more info please just write

edit:
I need to make it so that if parent1 !== and parent 2 is !== then it returns true, atm if either of them is !== it returns true

```
var parentIsFull = function (tree, index) {
    var parent1 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent1);
    var parent2 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent2);

    if (parent1 && (_state[tree][parent1] !== _talents[tree][parent1].ranks)) 
    if (parent2 && (_state[tree][parent2] !== _talents[tree][parent2].ranks))

        return false;
    return true;
};
```

Update:
The suggestion by Barmar worked perfectly! So thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like you need to just switch `true` and `false` here? Currently `return false` is executed when both conditions are fulfilled, `return true` in all other cases. Seems like you want the opposite.

Comment: also add your title question to description and clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the conditions with `||`

```
    if ((parent1 && (_state[tree][parent1] !== _talents[tree][parent1].ranks)) ||
        (parent2 && (_state[tree][parent2] !== _talents[tree][parent2].ranks))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Also, an `if/then` that just returns true or false can be written just as a single `return` statement.

```
return !((parent1 && (_state[tree][parent1] !== _talents[tree][parent1].ranks)) ||
         (parent2 && (_state[tree][parent2] !== _talents[tree][parent2].ranks)));
```